# How React can import objects from different components without import statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently learning React.js.

When you want to use a components in a different .js file, you need to import the component to the file you are working on. However, when I make a simple website, I didn't need to import an object inside of App.js into the file I am working on. I don't know why we don't have to explicitly specify that. If we don't import then, how React knows that what I am referring to?
Here's the screenshot of outcome and each components. The red dot line represent what I am talking about...
[image: Visual outcome]
[image: Object in App.js]
As the comment in the picture below says, I don't know how this file fetch the object in App.js...
[image: Calendar component (ExpenseDate.js)]
By the way, Expenses element another thing, but I added screenshot below just in case.
[image: ExpenseDate.js nested with Card.js component]

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: In App.js, in the component `<Expenses/>` You are passing the prop `items` to it with the expenses data. React handles all of the prop passing so all you have to do is access the `items` prop object in `<Expenses/>`. No need for imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're passing the `expenses` object through react component `props` and react will handle passing the data to your `Expenses` component.

If I want to clear this concept more, just imagine every react component as normal `function` in javascript. when you import a function in another file and you pass some data as `function argument` to the function you don't need to import that data again into the file that your `function` has been declared, you just use the argument of the function. `(which here is the component props)`

if you want to learn more about the props concepts in react, I suggest reading this page from react documents: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html